# GridView order changed when called notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, gridview

I want to create a Month Calendar using GridView in android.
Here is my code: (Sorry for my naming)
Activity class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_month_calendar);

    GridView calendar = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.month_view);
    final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item item;
    for (int i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        item = new Item();
        item.setDay(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        items.add(item);
    }

    List<String> yoteis = new ArrayList<String>();
    yoteis.add("Go to beach");
    items.get(15).setYotei(yoteis);

    final MonthCalendarAdapter adapter = new MonthCalendarAdapter(this, items); 
    calendar.setAdapter(adapter);

    calendar.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
                long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MonthCalendarActivity.this, "" + pos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
            List<String> newYoteis = new ArrayList<String>();
            newYoteis.add("new yotei");             
            items.get(pos).setYotei(newYoteis);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });
}
```

Adapter:

```
List<Item> items;
Context mContext;
public MonthCalendarAdapter(Context context,
        List<Item> objects) {
    super(context, 0, objects);
    mContext = context;
    items = objects;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    MonthCell cell;
    LayoutParams params = new GridView.LayoutParams(65,80);
    if(convertView == null) {
        cell = new MonthCell(mContext, items.get(position));
        cell.setLayoutParams(params);
        cell.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }else {
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
        cell = (MonthCell) convertView;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

MonthCell class:

```
public class MonthCell extends ImageView {

    Paint paint;
    Item item;
    public MonthCell(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public MonthCell(Context context, Item item) {
        this(context);      
        this.item = item;

    }   

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0, 176, 240));
        canvas.drawText(item.getDay(), 10, 20, paint);

        List<String> yoteis = item.getYotei();
        if(yoteis != null) {
            if(!yoteis.isEmpty()) {
                setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell);

                paint.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 124, 128));
                for(int i = 0; i < yoteis.size(); i++) {
                    canvas.drawText(yoteis.get(i), 10, 20 * (i + 2), paint);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

the first time Activity loaded, the screen is like this:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

8 9 10 ....

But when I click on the calendar, the order changed like this:

42 41 40 39 ....

....

7 6 5 4 3 2 1

(Sorry, I can't upload images because I have not enough reputation)
Can Anyone explain to me why that happened and how to resolve it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is due to incorrect usage of the convertView.  This assumption can be easily verified by using the following getView code

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  MonthCell cell;
  LayoutParams params = new GridView.LayoutParams(65,80);
  cell = new MonthCell(mContext, items.get(position));
  cell.setLayoutParams(params);
  cell.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
  return cell;
}
```

You can not assume that the convertView passed when requesting 'position' contains the item at 'position'.  You'll have to initialize the convertView correctly again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I used your code and it works correctly.
But I wonder that, in my case, there are no way to use convertView?

Comment: You should use convertView for performance reasons. But you'll have to initialize it correctly.  Your code somehow assumes that, when getView(position, convertView, ...) is called, that convertView contains items.get(position).  This assumption is not valid so you'll have to re-initialize convertView and set the correct item.

Comment: Mr jaredzhang's suggestion seem a good ideal for using convertView, but it still not work well. Can you suggest me how to initialize convertView correctly?

Comment: adding ((MonthCell)convertView).setItem(items.get(position)); seems correct to me. (and remove the public MonthCell(Context context, Item item) constructor and adding a MontCell.setItem(Item item){this.item=item;} function)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem happens here

```
   if(convertView == null) {
    cell = new MonthCell(mContext, items.get(position));
    cell.setLayoutParams(params);
    cell.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
}else {
    convertView.setLayoutParams(params);
    cell = (MonthCell) convertView;
}
```

try to modify like this:

```
   if(convertView == null) {
       convertView = new MonthCell(mContext, null);
       ((MonthCell)convertView).setLayoutParams(params);
       ((MonthCell)convertView).setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    }
    ((MonthCell)convertView).setItem(items.get(position));
```

Also in your customview `MonthCell` you should generate the getter for the field `item`

Comment: I tried to use convertView by using you code, the order not changed but items.get(position) seems not get correctly. When I click on one item, clicked cell and another cell's background has changed. I think, as Mr @Marc Van Daele said, "You can not assume that the convertView passed when requesting 'position' contains the item at 'position'"